# Local variable broken by closure capture when accessed in nested method

Tags: delphi, closures, anonymous-function, delphi-10-seattle

I've managed to reduce this problem to this :

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Threading;

procedure Foo(AString: string);
var
  LTask : ITask;
  capturedString : string;
  procedure Nested;
  begin
    try
      WriteLn('Nested : ' + capturedString); { ! EIntOverflow (Win32) here }
    except on E : Exception do
      WriteLn(E.Message);  
    end; 
  end;
begin
  capturedString := AString;
  WriteLn('Local : ' + capturedString);
  Nested;
  LTask := TTask.Create(
    procedure
      procedure AnonNested;
      begin
        WriteLn(capturedString); { Removing this eliminates the problem }
      end;
    begin
    end);
end;

begin
  Foo('foo');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Here the `capturedString` variable gets corrupted when accessed from within a nested method.  A Win32 compile raises `EIntOverflow`, a Win64 compile writes out a (corrupt) empty string - either build can be provoked into AV or other exceptions with some manipulation but in all cases the reference to the local variable is corrupted when entering the `Nested` procedure.

This seems to only happen if `capturedString` is captured in a closure.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a compiler bug that is resolved in 10.2 :

[#RSP-18833: Capture by closure corrupts local variable used in nested method](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18833)

A workaround is to use a second variable for capture in the anonymous method:

```
procedure Foo(AString: string);
var
  LTask : ITask;
  capturedString, s2 : string;
  procedure Nested;
  begin
    try
      WriteLn('Nested : ' + capturedString);
    except on E : Exception do
      WriteLn(E.Message);  { !!! }
    end; 
  end;
begin
  capturedString := AString;
  s2 := capturedString;
  WriteLn('Local : ' + capturedString);
  Nested;
  LTask := TTask.Create(
    procedure
      procedure AnonNested;
      begin
        WriteLn(s2); { Capture another variable }
      end;
    begin
    end);
end;
```